# save all of the user input into text file in c

Tags: c, file, text, struct, save

I am trying to save all the input "owner records" into the text file, but I only end up saving the last input record. When I also try and have 2 pet records, the last record only gets saved. How do I modify the program in order to save all the "records" into the text file without overwriting the previous inputs?

Below is the program I've written:

```
typedef char String[30];

struct ownerTag {
   String ownerName, address, contactNum;
   struct petTag {
      String petName, type;
   } pets[5];
} record;

struct ownerTag createRecord(){
int i, m;
FILE *fp2;
fp2 = fopen("Record.txt", "w");

scanf("%s", record.ownerName);
fprintf(fp2, "%s\n", record.ownerName);
scanf("%s", record.address);
fprintf(fp2, "%s\n", record.address);
scanf("%s", record.contactNum);
fprintf(fp2, "%s\n", record.contactNum);

for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    scanf("%s", record.pets[i].petName);
    fprintf(fp2, "%s\n", record.pets[i].petName);
    scanf("%s", record.pets[i].type);
    fprintf(fp2, "%s\n", record.pets[i].type);
    printf("\n");
}
fclose(fp2);
return record; }

int main(){
int i, n;
String search;

struct ownerTag owner[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        owner[i] = createRecord();
    }
return 0;}
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Please specify the exact input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Your program would be easier to test if you made the program output a prompt when the user is supposed to provide input, and if that prompt specified what the user was supposed to input (i.e. name, address).

Comment: If possible, please provide a [mre] of the problem (one that doesn't require more than 10 lines of input in order to reproduce the problem).

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements

Answer (score 2):

In every function call of `createRecord`, you exectute the following line once:

`fp2 = fopen("Record.txt", "w");`

This line will overwrite any existing file by that name, deleting its contents. That is what the "write" mode `"w"` does.

Since you call the function `createRecord` 10 times (once per loop iteration), the contents of the file created in the first 9 iterations of the loop will be deleted.

Therefore, you have two options to fix the problem:

- open the file in "append" mode `"a"` instead of "write" mode `"w"`, or
- open the file only once in your program, at the start of `main`, instead of 10 times.

I recommend the second option.